# Pass variable from child view to parent view in Swift

Tags: swift, parent-child, key-value-observing

I'm trying to pass a variable from a child view (inputPopUp.swift) to a parent view using setter and getter functions. Here is the code in my child view:

```
var char: String!
var buttonPressed = String()

@IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonPressed = "addButton"
    setChar("+")
    getChar()
    self.removeAnimate()
}

@IBAction func minusButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonPressed = "minusButton"
    setChar("-")
    self.removeAnimate()
}

@IBAction func divideButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonPressed = "divideButton"
    setChar("/")
    self.removeAnimate()
}

@IBAction func multiplyButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    buttonPressed = "multiplyButton"
    setChar("*")
    self.removeAnimate()
}

//setter method
func setChar(var thisChar: String){
    char = thisChar
}

//getter method
func getChar()-> String{
    if (buttonPressed == "addButton"){
        char = "+"
    }
    if (buttonPressed == "minusButton"){
        char = "-"
    }
    if (buttonPressed == "divideButton"){
        char = "/"
    }
    if (buttonPressed == "multiplyButton"){
        char = "*"
    }
    return char
}
```

I am trying to access the 'char' variable in my parent view like so, however it is returning nil - presumably because I am calling a new instance of the function.

```
@IBAction func runButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    inputPopUp().getChar()
}
```

### How can I pass the data from the child to the parent effectively?

I would also like to update a label in my parent view, based on the button click within my child view. I am trying to implement Key-Value Observation. Here's what I've got so far.

```
class ObserveChar: NSObject {

dynamic var char = String()

func updateChar(){

    char = String()
}
```

}

```
private var myContext = 0

class Observer: NSObject {

var objectToObserve = ObserveChar()

override init(){

    super.init()

    objectToObserve.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "char", options: .New, context: &myContext)
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    if context == &myContext {

        println("Char updated: \(change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey])")

    } else {
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}

deinit {

    objectToObserve.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "char", context: &myContext)

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok，Maybe you can set the child view as a property of parent view,maybe like this

```
var inputPopView : inputPopUp       /**<initialize it somewhere */
```

and then you can use it like this

```
@IBAction func runButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
self.inputPopView.getChar() 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So how might I now change a label in the parent view, based on the result of the child view? I have this so far, unfortunately it's throwing an error of nil. `ParentView().tapLabel.text = getChar()`

Comment: Your project is about a  calculator? Two ways,

Comment: Something like that. It's a simple app to teach kids how to code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your project is about calculator. You should not use

`ParentView().tapLabel.text = getChar()`
because, You have created parentView many times, you should set parentView as its weak property

You can also use KVO to observe child view's char variable;or  you can also use NSNotification to update parent view's tapLabel;Or you can also use delegate.
The delegate likes below

```
protocol UpdateTapLabel {
func didTapSomeOperateAction(operateInfo : String)
```

}

```
class ParentClass : NSObject, UpdateTapLabel {
var tapLabel : UILabel!
var childView : ChildView!
func didTapSomeOperateAction(operateInfo: String) {
    self.tapLabel.text = operateInfo
}
//you should initialize the child view like this
/*
childView = ChildView()
childView.delegate = self
*/
```

}

```
class ChildView: NSObject {
var char: String!
var delegate : UpdateTapLabel
//getter method
func getChar() {
    if (buttonPressed == "addButton"){
        char = "+"
    }
    if (buttonPressed == "minusButton"){
        char = "-"
    }
    if (buttonPressed == "divideButton"){
        char = "/"
    }
    if (buttonPressed == "multiplyButton"){
        char = "*"
    }
    self.delegate.didTapSomeOperateAction(char)
}
```

}

The KVO likes below

```
//you should add observer like this
//self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "childView.char", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
//also you should remove it in deinit, otherwise you will get crash when release parentView
deinit {
    self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "childView.char")
}
//you can handle the kvo here
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "childView.char" {
        self.tapLabel.text = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to ask my class to inherit NSObject, as it is already a UIViewController, should I create a new class?

Comment: Oh no, I just use NSObject as an example,you should ask your class inherit hickey

Comment: You should ask your class inherit Uiview or Uiviecontroller or some else